# Tracking time spent in iOS applications

Tags: ios, applications

I know [RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com/) exists for [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rescuetime.android&hl=en) but I do not see anything like it for iOS. I'm guessing such an app may not be possible on iOS because of the permissions and how apps have been sandboxed from one another. However, I'm hoping that I'm wrong.

Has anyone found an app which at the end of the day a user could look and see a list which shows the total active time spent in different applications for that day?

I'm looking for something like the following:

```
Summary for YYYY-MM-DD
Total Time: 2h28m

 - Safari: 48m 
 - Tweetbot: 32m 
 - Mail: 23m 
 - Cooks Illustrated: 22m 
 - Yelp: 12m
 - Messages: 8m 
 - OmniFocus: 3m
```

Comment: Is jailbreaking an option? There was a jailbreak app back in iOS 6 that did this.

Comment: I'd prefer not to jailbreak the phone. But as highlighted by @Tibor_Ku in the answer below, because of the security constraints that might be the only way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such app for iOS because of its security limitations, you can see such statistics only once jailbroken.

That being said, you will find something close to what you are looking for but only if you are using iOS 9. Do the following: Settings > Battery and under Battery if you scroll down by a little bit, you will see battery usage for the last 24 hours or for the last 7 days in % and in min/h on screen time and background usage also in min/h, something like the image below.

[image: Battery usage]

Comment: This is what I suspected and this screen gives an look at the information but my curiosity was to see over time how it is changing. I wanted to remove/voluntarily stop using certain apps and see how my usage changes.

Comment: @cclark Well I too would like an app that could give me that information and the option to save it within that app, but this is as close as it gets, althought you could take a screenshot at the end of every day and store it somewhere on your own (Some king of cloud service like Dropbox etc.) and then do everything you want this way.

Comment: @Tibor_Ku Is it possible to track installed apps usage on iOS devices using MDM profiles?

Answer (score 4):

The beta of iOS 12 includes [Screen Time](https://www.apple.com/uk/newsroom/2018/06/ios-12-introduces-new-features-to-reduce-interruptions-and-manage-screen-time/) which solves this problem rather conclusively at the OS level. Here's a couple of my screenshots from revent use: [image][image]

Comment: There is no public API for developers though right ?

Comment: settings -> Screen Time